# Where does UserDetail fit in domain and aggregate?

Tags: c#, .net, database, class-design, aggregate

I'm unsure how to deal with the UserDetail class.

*Program;* A virtual account hierarchy, with UserAccounts which can only have transactions towards a MainAccount. But the UserAccounts can place some type of bets, which will be a profit/loss towards the account balance.

It feels logical to have MainAccount as the database aggregate root, as the accounts form the most important data. As it looks now, it may seem ok to have the UserDetail as part of the account aggregate, but I it could be useful to create a user even before an account has been created. And perhaps a user also may be allowed to have two accounts. Then what?

I guess the UserDetail could be simply a stand-alone aggregate. But in such case, how would I load the respective UserDetail when loading the account aggregate?

Please, if you have some thoughts around this, would be much appreciated.

*Btw, I'm using FluentNHibernate.*

Domain:

```
    public class MainCashAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IList<UserCashAccount> UserCashAccounts { get; set; }
        public IList<Transaction> UserAccountTransactions { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserCashAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public UserDetail User { get; set; }
        public IList<Bet> Bets { get; set; }

        public UserConnection Connection { get; set; }   // Not persisted/mapped
    }
    public class UserDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Other:

```
    public class UserConnection
    {
        public TcpClient TcpClient { get; set; }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Possible solutions:   (??)

**One-Directional**

```
Class UserCashAccountMap
   ...
   HasOne(x => x.User).Cascade.None()
```

**Bi-Directional**

```
Class UserDetail
   ...(as above)
   public UserCashAccount Account {get; set;}

Class UserCashAccountMap
   ...
   HasOne(x => x.User).Cascade.None()

Class UserDetail
   HasOne(x => x.Account).Cascade.None().Inverse()
```

*..Or Reference instead of HasOne, for allowing multiple accounts per user.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the UserDetail could be simply a stand-alone aggregate. But in such case, how would I load the respective UserDetail when loading the account aggregate?

By having the primary key of the MainAccount object be a foreign key on the UserDetail object.

The question you specifically revolves around to have self referencing entities or not, from your statements I quoted you could define your model in a bunch of ways. You could do

```
public class UserCashAccount {
    public IList<UserDetail> Details {get;set;}
}

public class Details {
    public UserCashAccount Account {get;set;}
}

public class UserCashAccount {
    public Guid UserDetailsId {get;set;}
}

public class Details {
    public Guid AccountId {get;set;}
}
```

or any combination of these 2. You can also choose to not reference 1 side of this relationship at all and not have a bi-directional relationship.

**Edit:** Responding to your comment. You do not want to use `HasOne()`, HasOne is an extremely rare type of association that is truly 1-to-1, almost no databases ever have relationships coded as a 1-to-1 they are almost always many-to-1. This is a `References()` relationship.

In the situation of a HasOne both objects share the same primary key. This design is almost never used in database systems.

One note I did originally have an error in my design, to have a bi-directional association the UserDetails would actually be a collection on the UserAccount object to avoid requiring a true HasOne association.

Comment: Note if you go the ID route you obviously have to manually load an object at some point.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure this is simple I just have a little brain-block, as I never done this before. Would I understand you correct that I could just add a property "UserCashAccount Account" to the UserDetail class, and map it as HasOne(x => x.Account).Cascade.None()?  Hmm, that would make it bidirectional, maybe not necessary..

Comment: Or wait.. Maybe I could just leave it as I posted, and map the User property of UserCashAccount as HasOne(...).Cascade.None ?  That is all that's required and would make the UserDetail a separate aggregate?

Comment: I responded to you in my answer

Comment: Ok, I must admit I didn't really get what you meant by "Main" in your examples. The class MainCashAccount I have is not user specific, it's a single account which all the UserAccounts (all users) are sub-accounts of.  But I edited with some possible solution, if that's correct then I guess for one-directional my domain can remain as it is.. (?)

Comment: I see. Yes if allowing multiple accounts it must be Reference of course.

Comment: Regarding my note on why it should be a collection is why I almost never code bidirectional associations except in the case of a Many-to-Many relationship. It's possible in your design you might want to use Component objects that share 1 overall database table but give you the nested objects for your application.

Comment: "should be a collection".. I thought bi-directional 1:m was possible, by using HasMany and Reference on respective sides. But when I think about it it's not really anything that enforces them to be circular reference, so maybe that's what you mean?  I haven't used component objects before, but yes I'm somewhat aware this can substitute 1:1 tables.

Comment: @bretddog yes bidirection 1:m is definitely possible, but as the one side is M it needs to have a collection. Since 1 user detail will always have 1 account, but theoretically a useraccount could have many details even if in practice it would only have 1 detail. I've almost always found the many side of the relationship to be a code smell on my domain models as I've almost never needed a true bidirectional association YMMV on that part.

Comment: I can't see why one would put a collection if it's not needed in the domain. Either it's a 1:1, and coded as such, or it's 1:m, with one collection. And both could be coded as bi-directional, but with the need of custom add/remove methods to keep the relationship in sync on both sides. (I thought) Well, maybe I don't really get your point.  In this case though, if one wanted 1:m, I think it would be more realistic to have multiple accounts for any user.